# Upgrade related questions appropriate?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

Appropriate to ask for advice on upgrading on this site?

For instance, if a user says "I have this computer was set up a, and $500 to spend, what are the best upgrades to spend my money on?", will this be allowed?

Comment: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with "no" here -- it's a shopping question as you phrased it. Any recommendations that involve spending money are highly time-limited.

If you remove the dollars and simply ask:

> If I was going to upgrade my computer, in what order should I upgrade components to get the most performance for my money?

That would be slightly less contentious question and probably one I wouldn't vote to close as it will stay true much longer than a I-have-dollars-to-spend question.

Comment: But it is unanserable as it depends on what you are doing.  If running say VMNs you might need to get the RAM up to a high number if compiling or video editing I'll suspect an SSD. If just compiling then a fusion drive might be best. If games then a video card So it depends And it changes over time

Comment: @Mark yes, I did qualify my rephrasing of the question with the adjective "slightly", did I not? Indeed, I did. I disagree it's unanswerable. It's not a great question. But it's not off topic.